# Migrate Vb to Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Hai Friends

I having the project in Vb i want to migrate that project in the vb.net.any tool available pls inform me.i have tried a lot.i have not installed the visual basic.with the help of remote server i am running that project.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few versions of Visual studio have a built-in Upgrade Wizard to help you with converting VB6 to Vb.Net code. I know that VS 2005 Pro has it but I'm not sure what other versions.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239677%28VS.60%29.aspx)'s an article about how to go about upgrading. And there's even a complete free e-book about it as can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788236.aspx).

Comment: VS 2005 and VS 2008 have the Wizard. It's been discontinued in VS 2010, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the sources Ho1 mentions some of the biggest pitfalls are the lack of control arrays, printing and graphics. The printing can be partly mitigated by the use of Printer Compatibility. You can download the PCL as part of the [Visual Basic Power Pack 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/aa701257.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you have room in your budget I would recommend ArtinSoft.  www.artinsoft.com.  They have a trial version that you can test out.  They have been named Microsoft's preferred VB to .NET upgrade solution provider.

Comment: I hadn't seen that Artinsoft had been named as the preferred upgrade solution provider, do you have a link for that? This page at Microsoft UK recommends them equally with CodeArchitect's VB Migration Partner. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dd408373.aspx

Comment: Here is the link.  http://www.artinsoft.com/vb-migration-overview.aspx.

Under the Microsoft seal of approval it states the following.  "ArtinSoft, a Certified Partner and member of the Visual Studio Integration Program (VSIP), has been named Microsoft’s preferred VB to .NET upgrade solution provider."

Comment: Artinsoft's pricing strategy has changed twice in recent times. They used to have a 'developer' edition (not entirely sure about the name) which was cheaper than the 'Full' version then they dropped that.
The full version was available in 2 lines one of which allowed for upgrade to vb.net only and the other which allowed for upgrade to either vb.net or C#. The latter was priced at twice the former. Well the upgrade to vb.net only option has been dropped which effectively means a doubling in price for people wishing to upgrade to vb.net.

Comment: Also tehir licensing states that "Licensing is per application, allowing to run the VBUC several times upon the same VB6 files."
I suspect that this might mean that there is some DRM functionality in their app that will limit the number of times you can run the program and even possibly control which files can be used as input.
If that is the case then it's a major turn off for me. I don't need having to be careful how many times I run something. I could see myself wanting to convert, tweak something in the vb6 code then convert again, lots of times.

Answer (score 0):

I have trialed artinsoft's upgrade companion.
I have also looked at vbmigration partner.
This is my, very limited, anecdotal experience.
On vbmigration partner they have some sample conversions of projects they found on planat sourcecode.
One is call ezdatabase.
If you run vbmigration partner's conversion it will crash if you click the connect/disconnect button more than twice.
On the vb6 version you can click this all day without crashing.
This project is small enough to put through the artinsoft trial of vbuc in its entirety, so i did that.
However after i converted it, there seemed to be a lot of compile errors.

It's not a fair comparison as obviously vb migration partner had lots of opportunity to perfect it before putting the converted code on their website. and yet it was easy to crash.
However I was also disappointed with artinsoft's tool as this was just a small (few hundred lines)  crud application and yet there were a lot of compile errors.

Make of this what you will. I would like to hear of others' experiences.

EDIT : On the other hand if this is a true test of the relative capabilities of vb migration partner and artinsoft vbuc then vb migration arner is clearly the winner in this example

Comment: EDIT: There is another option. http://www.greatmigrations.com/ has a tool that is fully configurable by setting up rules that gets your code to 100% and over in the click of a button.  You don't hand fix any of the code, as you do with artinsoft and vb migration partner.